# How to set textview position when created dynamically in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, programmatically-created

I want to dynamically change the position of the `textview` list dynamically. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;
TextView rowTextView = new TextView(Oyun.this);

rowTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.parent);
myTextViews[atesSayac].setText("This is row #" + atesSayac);
myTextViews[atesSayac] = rowTextView;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myTextViews[atesSayac].getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myTextViews[atesSayac].getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

myTextViews[atesSayac].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
myTextViews[atesSayac].setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

myTextViews[atesSayac].setTranslationX(locationX);
myTextViews[atesSayac].setTranslationY(locationY);

atesEt.addView(myTextViews[atesSayac]);
```

Comment: Updated the grammar, cleaned up the code example and made the question more readable.

Comment: Removed the Dynamic programming tag. It doesn't relate here.